# jquery - How do i access specific data in json

Tags: jquery, json

i have this json :

```
{
"series": [
    {
        "name": "RegularDeposit",
        "data": [
            22, << == i wanted to have access on this line only
            33,
            44
        ]
    }
]
}
```

i begin with output like `series.data`

But it displaying `Object Object`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need `series[0].data[0]`?

Series is an array in your example.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/shE58/10/)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
var data={
 "series": [{
    "name": "RegularDeposit",
    "data": [
        22, 
        33,
        44
     ]
    }
 ]}

 alert(data.series[0].data[0]);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shE58/11/)